# Is there a shell script where we can update two files and change a line in the third file

Tags: python, shell

I have three files in a server. I want to update first file with content A and update second file with content B. In the third file i want to replace the last line with content C. At the end I want to restart few services.

Comment: If you have a question about a specific mechanism that isnt working or you're having a problem with an existing script then we can help you, otherwise this question is far too broad.

Answer (score -1):

You can use paramico to connect to sftp server using ssh.In the below code replace the texts enclosed within # with relevant field.You can loop 'ssh.exec_command 'with your commands to perform the task

```
 import paramiko
 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 ssh.connect('#Host address#', username='#username#', password='#password#')
 stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('#commands#')
 ssh.close()
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Could you please explain?

Comment: You can access the files on a server and modify it using the above method through sftp same as how you use putty for ssh connection